# Can Zeno's Dichotomy Paradox be used in a proof?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, paradoxes

I've been watching multiple videos on the subject of Zeno's Dichotomy Paradox. Specifically, I have been looking into the paradox of halving distances. Where you continuously halve the distance from Point A to Point B an infinite number of times. In at least one or two of the videos I watched they showed a simplistic mathematics proof for the paradox.

Here's my question or dilemma. I've stumbled upon something that looks like Zeno's Paradox, in a completely unrelated problem. Could I use the same proof used in Zeno's Paradox to help my proof in this other problem? Or is Zeno's Paradox technically not considered to have a proven solution and therefore could not be used as part of the proof for this other problem?

Comment: Zeno's "paradox" is not now considered one, since all can be explained using ideas from the topic of convergent infinite sums.

Comment: What do you mean by "the ... proof used in Zeno's Paradox"?

Comment: Would it be wrong to point out the similarities in the question I am working on and Zeno's Paradox, or should I just use convergent infinite sums?

Comment: To me if your question can be filled out, completely, as to its relation to *both* topics of Zeno's paradox *and* the rigorous use of infinite sums, that would be preferrable to simply discussing infinite sums, since the latter is completely known.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC specifically I am looking at a Probability question. 50% of the time produces one outcome. 25% of the time produces a second outcome. 12.5% gives a third. This pattern repeats infinitely. I noticed that the percentage values basically reflect Zeno's Dichotomy Paradox. So, should I point out this fact and proof in my proof?

Comment: In my opinion, along the lines of @coffeemath's, make sure you rigorously prove your claim with modern infinite sums language, and then, if it strikes you as interesting, point out the parallel to Zeno.

Comment: IMHO, if you use the terminology "[geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)", you show more maturity than if you say "this goes just like in the video I watched about Zeno's paradox".

Comment: I would say no, don't mention Zeno's paradox. Geometric series show up all the time, especially the one with common ratio 1/2. It doesn't make sense to mention Zeno's dichotomy paradox every time, unless there is more of a connection than just the geometric series. In this case, there doesn't seem to be anything paradoxical about the probability problem.